# Java Format number: Fixed length, variable precision

Tags: java, precision, number-formatting, fixed-width

I do have a text file which contains numbers with a fixed maximum length and a variable precision:

- Maximum precision 14
- maximum length 16 (precision + decimal-point + integer number)
- optional/additional - sign
- optional/additional exponent

Example file:

```
 9,79807071728185E-04
-5,05136986567715E-03
19,7704499139572
21,7994214067998
```

Example Java output:

```
 9.798070717281847E-4
-0.00505136986567715
19.77044991395723
21.799421406799794
```

I would like to print the java output exactly the same as the number in the file in order to compare via `diff` tool

So far I tried:

```
new DecimalFormat("0.##############E00").format(value)
```

- Which always writes the E (E00 should be omitted - only E01, E02, etc. are needed)
- Always makes only one digit before the decimal point

Comment: You seem to be asking for a format that maximizes the displayed precision by ensuring that the decimal point is aligned within 2 digits of the leftmost non-zero digit.  But that's a guess based on what you've shown.  For example, how would `0.05283741212312` display? Would it be `5.28374121231200E-02`?  Is the rule _"max 2 digits left of the decimal, max 2 zeros right of the decimal?"_  If so, there's probably not a builtin way to accomplish this, you'll have to examine each number and choose the proper format based on its magnitude in decimal.

Comment: It would be displayed as 0.05283741212312 the scientific format sould only be used if needed. Trailing zeroes are not display (which is ok / as expected)

Comment: I also think that the format in the file is very strange and try to request a file with a more standard format